# Minimization word problem. Fence enclosure.

Tags: calculus, optimization

A farmer wishes to fence a rectangular pasture of area $2800~m^2$. One side of the fence is along a road, and that side costs \$5 per meter. The other 3 sides cost \$2 per meter.

Find the minimum possible cost.

I would be able to do this if all of the sides cost the same, but the fact that the one side costs \$5 throws me off. I understand that the formula will be $xy = 2800$. But I do not know how to represent the variables and isolate them.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Dollar signs carry special significance on this site (see [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more details). Therefore, if you want actual dollar signs, you have to tell the site that those are actual dollar signs, and you do that by putting a backslash in front of them, like so: `\$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be the length of the side along the road and let $y$ be the length of the sides perpendicular to the road. Then you know that $xy=2\,800$, which means that $y=\frac{2\,800}x$. He will pay $x\times5\$+x\times2\$+y\times2\$+y\times2\$$ for the fence; in other words, the cost (in dollars) will be $7x+4y$. But since $y=\frac{2\,800}x$, this means that the farmer will pay $7x+\frac{11\,200}x$ dollars. Let $c(x)=7x+\frac{11\,200}x$. Then $c'(x)=7-\frac{11\,200}{x^2}$ and the only positive $x$ such that $c'(x)=0$ is $x=40$. Furthermore, $c'(x)>0$ if $c>40$ and $c'(x)<0$ if $x<40$. Therefore, the minimum of $c$ is $c(40)=560$ and the farmer will have to pay $560\$$.

Answer (score 1):

The sides of the  rectangular pasture are $x$ (meter) and $y$ (meter), where the side along the road has length $x$ (meter). The costs are therefore (in dollars):

$c(x,y)=5x+2x+2y+2y=7x+4y$

You have to minimize the function $c(x,y)=7x+4y$ with the constraint $xy=2800$.

Hence $y=\frac{2800}{x}$.

Thus your problem ist to minimize the function

$f(x)=7x+4 \frac{2800}{x}$.

Comment: I think the cost function $c(x,y)$ should be $5x+2x+2y+2y$

Comment: OOOps ! you are right !